# Sending data from Base Activity to Fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a query regarding fragment.
Scenario is: After I login, I am on an actiivity  which have 3 fragments. For fragments I have used ViewPager. Now I have to use login username in one of my fragment. I have bought username from login page using putExtra. My query is how take that username to the fragments ??

Comment: put them in bundle and pass them to your fragment. 
I recommend you to use shared-preference for this .

Comment: Why are you not using shared preference for this ?

Comment: You are right. Can be done from that also but I did bundle thing but got null pointer exception in fragment. Any idea!!

Comment: Dont know how to use shared preference.

Comment: It will be helpful if you share code snippet

Answer (score 1):

From your BaseActivity send data with `intent` :

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("username", "From your BaseActivity");
// set Fragmentclass Arguments
Fragmentclass fragmentclass = new Fragmentclass();
fragmentclass .setArguments(bundle);
```

And in your `Fragment` `onCreatView` method :

```
@Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String username= getArguments().getString("username");    
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourFragment, container, false);
}
```

Comment: It shows null pointer Exception in the fragment at line where we are storing value in String.

Comment: @ArmanReyaz  you should set the bundle before adding the fragment to your Activity

Answer (score 1):

You can also use SharedPreferences.
Store the username or what so ever you want to save in SharedPreferences and use it anywhere in your app.
For your reference [SharedPreferences Tutorials](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)

Answer (score 0):

From your activity you can send data with intent:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("username", "abcd");
// set Fragmentclass Arguments
FragmentClass frag_one = new Fragmentclass();
frag_one.setArguments(bundle);
```

and add below code in Fragment onCreateView method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
String strtext = getArguments().getString("username");    
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
}
```

Comment: It shows null pointer Exception in the fragment at line where we are storing value in String.

Comment: @ArmanReyaz Can you try String strtext = this.getArguments().getString("username");